# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' while using Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, getenv

I am trying to run the simple below snippet

```
port = int(os.getenv('PORT'))
print("Starting app on port %d" % port)
```

I can understand the PORT is s string but I need to cast to a int. Why I am getting the error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: It is highly likely that, you forgot to `export PORT`. Hence there's no `PORT` in the env, hence it returns `None`

Comment: Is there a reasonable default port for this app? Then `os.getenv('PORT', default_port)` would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have an environment variable called `PORT`.

`os.getenv('PORT')` -> returns `None` -> throws exception when you try to convert it to int

Before running your script, create in your terminal the environment variable by:

```
export PORT=1234
```

Or, you can provide a default port in case it's not defined as an environment variable on your machine:

```
DEFAULT_PORT = 1234
port = int(os.getenv('PORT',DEFAULT_PORT))
print("Starting app on port %d" % port)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for commenting and giving the solutions. Actually there was no port assigned in my local system and thats the reason for it. Sou both are right.