# TypeError when running an API from a GitLab project

Tags: python, windows, pipenv

I got access to a private GitLab project that contains the following branches: `main`, `develop` and `new_branch`. The machine learning project is pretty complex and contains various transformers for NLP, and many steps that generate some output from an input text. FastAPI has also been used.

I am trying to see how this works and run it. I use Windows. I know that I need Python 3.9 and to have `pipenv` installed and then the following instructions are given:

```
Install all dependencies locally by running `pipenv install --dev`. 
Create an empty file named `.env` inside the root project folder. 
Copy and paste the contents of the `.env.example` file into `.env`. 
Run `pipenv run prebuild-win` to download the necessary static files needed by 3rd party libraries. 
Run API using the following command: `pipenv run start`. Go to `http://localhost:8000/`.
```

I opened git CMD, cloned it, and it's the `develop` branch that appears in the folder (for the `new_branch` it says `Pipeline: failed`). I navigated to the folder of the project, created a virtual environment and installed the dependencies. The file that in GitLab was called `.env.example` already appear in my folder as `.env` with the necessary contents. I run `pipenv run prebuild-win` and everything else gets installed.

But when I run API using `pipenv run start`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\me\the-project\app\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    api = Api()
  File "C:\Users\me\the-project\app\main.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.config_service = ConfigService()
  File "C:\Users\me\the-project\app\core\config.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.port = int(os.getenv('PORT'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Did I do anything wrong?

I checked and there is a port, and I think it's because I skipped the creating an `.env` file step. I created an empty text file, copy and pasted the contents, and I get the same error. The `.env.example` contains:

```
APP_NAME=My app
VERSION=0.0.1
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=1234
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' while using Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61697523/typeerror-int-argument-must-be-a-string-a-bytes-like-object-or-a-number-not)

Comment: @abc I saw this question and I do have a port. I added an edit to the question. I thought the problem was not creating that .env file. But I now did create it and I get the same error.

Comment: @abc So I managed to make that step work, but now if I go to localhost I just get {"name":"My app","version":"0.0.1","currentTime":"01/07/2022, 04:11:55"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int(os.getenv('PORT'))
```

This line tries to read the environment variable `PORT` and convert it to an integer.

The fact that you get the error

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

indicates that `os.getenv('PORT')` returned `None`, i.e. that the environment variable did not exist.

You need to find out how to set the appropriate environment variables. Apparently writing them into a file called `.env` isn't sufficient.

Comment: I managed to do it by writing them into the `.env` file eventually, but thank you! I will accept your answer. The problem is now that when I go to `http://localhost:8000/` I only get `{"name":"My app","version":"0.0.1","currentTime":"01/07/2022, 04:16:47"}` and in the terminal `"←[1mGET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m404 Not Found←[0m`. Is that a problem? How do I actually open and play around with the app?